# Нужно сделать обводку при наведении

Tags: html, css, анимация, transform

Есть у меня вот такая реализация, где при наведении плавно появляется нижний бордер, а теперь нужно в таком стиле сделать весь прямоугольник

Код, это все что слева

```css
.order-row {
  display: flex;
  width: 50%;
  height: 84vh;
  margin-top: 1vh;
  background: url(../img/14days.jpg) no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}

.link {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
}

.link h2 {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  font-weight: 400;
}

.link-order {
  width: 435px;
  height: 130px;
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

.link-order h2::after {
  display: block;
  content: '';
  border-bottom: 1px solid #2d2d2d;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 100% 50%;
  transition: transform 450ms ease-in-out;
}

.link-order h2:hover::after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  transform-origin: 0% 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="order-row">
  <div class="link link-order">
    <h2><a href="#">Под заказ за 14 дней</a></h2>
  </div>
</div>
```

[image: Реализовано то что слева]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Лучший вариант такой анимации без использования SVG будет выглядеть так:

```css
* {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100vh;
  display: -webkit-box;
  display: -ms-flexbox;
  display: flex;
  -webkit-box-pack: center;
      -ms-flex-pack: center;
          justify-content: center;
  -webkit-box-align: center;
      -ms-flex-align: center;
          align-items: center;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

a {
  position: relative;
  color: #333;
  font-family: Arial, "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, sans-serif;
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px transparent;
          box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 2px transparent;
  padding: 20px 40px;
}

a:after,
a:before {
  content: '';
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
          box-sizing: border-box;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
}

a:after {
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.8s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.6s, height 0.2s ease-in 0.4s;
  -o-transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.8s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.6s, height 0.2s ease-in 0.4s;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.8s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.6s, height 0.2s ease-in 0.4s;
}

a:before {
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.2s, height 0.2s ease-in;
  -o-transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.2s, height 0.2s ease-in;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-in 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-in 0.2s, height 0.2s ease-in;
}

a:hover:after,
a:hover:before {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

a:hover:after {
  border-top-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-right-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
  -o-transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
  transition: width 0.2s ease-out, height 0.2s ease-out 0.2s;
}

a:hover:before {
  border-bottom-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  border-left-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, .3);
  -webkit-transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-out 0.4s, height 0.2s ease-out 0.6s;
  -o-transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-out 0.4s, height 0.2s ease-out 0.6s;
  transition: border-color 0s ease-out 0.4s, width 0.2s ease-out 0.4s, height 0.2s ease-out 0.6s;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">Сделать заказ</a>
```

Comment: Вообще огонь) Спасибо

Comment: хах) Алексей я сейчас учусь на 3-ем курсе Информатики в Крну Остроградского) В начале, так сказать, своего пути. Не ожидал увидеть земляка, та и еще с такой карьерой)

Comment: @ДмитрийЛебедь спасибо. Напишите мне через контакты из сайта в профиле. Если будет желание и умение, сможем поработать.

Answer (score 2):

Есть два варианта, первый:

```css
button {
  padding: .5em 1em;
  border: none;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

button:after {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
  content: ' ';
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border: 1px solid;
  border-right-width: 0;
  transform: scaleX(0);
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  transition: transform .3s, border .1s .3s;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

button:hover:after {
  transform: scaleX(1);
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<button>click me</button>
```

И второй:

```css
.rect {
  fill: lightblue;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
}

.rect:hover {
  stroke-dashoffset: 0;
}
```

```html
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="205" height="55">
  <rect width="200" height="50" x="1" y="1" class="rect" />
</svg>
```

Comment: Второй вариант то что надо, большое спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

А я умею `clip-path`, поэтому анимируются все 4 стороны. Но кроссбораузерность так себе.

```css
div {
  float: left;
  line-height: 2em;
  padding: 0 2em;
  background: silver;
  
  border: 2px solid blue;
  transition: clip-path 1s linear;
  
  clip-path: polygon(
    2px 0,
    2px 0, 2px 2px, /* moving */
    100% 2px,
    100% 2px, calc(100% - 2px) 2px, /* moving */
    calc(100% - 2px) 100%,
    calc(100% - 2px) 100%, calc(100% - 2px) calc(100% - 2px), /* moving */
    0 calc(100% - 2px),
    0 calc(100% - 2px), 2px calc(100% - 2px) /* moving */
  );
}

div:hover {
  clip-path: polygon(
    2px 0,
    100% 0, 100% 2px, /* moving */
    100% 2px,
    100% 100%, calc(100% - 2px) 100%, /* moving */
    calc(100% - 2px) 100%,
    0 100%, 0 calc(100% - 2px), /* moving */
    0 calc(100% - 2px),
    0 0, 2px 0 /* moving */
  );
}
```

```html
<div>Hover me</div>
```

Comment: круто, намотаю себе на ус)

Comment: и даже плюсик не поставил :(

Comment: держи) я твой труд оценил